# How to pass data in dialog angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have created a dialog to save a name with random id, now I did another click button to open me another dialog, in that dialog name should be passed so I can change the name.
The name is not always the same changes every time. I created an store with  angular ngrx that is the reason that if I want to edit to trigger the name or to pass the name.
I did some things but doesn't work.
Here is a code that opens the dialog.

```
openprojecteditdialog() {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ProjectEditDialogComponent, {
  disableClose: true,
});
dialogRef.componentInstance.newProjectName = 'project';  }
```

If you need some extra code let me know I will post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular 4 , Data passing to modal from component is same as component to component communication. Parameter variable name and Injector variable name should be same. Check bellow

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ProjectEditDialogComponent, {
     genericObj : { 
                   disableClose: true,
                  }
});
```

**genericObj** is parameter variable name should be same as injector variable name in Dialog modal. check bellow code

```
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public genericObj : any) { }
```

here the injector variable name should be **genericObj** . 
I hope you done mistake here.

Comment: Thanks, but @Inject should i implement to my dialog constructor or to my page where i call the dialog open ?

Comment: I did that but still don't work, my problem is that name is always different so when i want to edit that name open another dialog in that dialog pass the current name so i can change or something like this.

Comment: what ever the dynamic data you need to send wrap it with common variable name and pass inside modal Ex : const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ProjectEditDialogComponent, {
     genericObject : {disableClose : true});

Comment: It is possible to Pass the Data but not with dialog component to component like in dialog we write in the constructor ?